# Count file in linux by between date time

Tags: linux, count, between, wc

I would like to ask about how to count the number of files in linux by between two dates and times?

Example I have 10 file like:

```
Date Modified      Filename
2016101500         1.file
2016101501         2.file
2016101502         3.file
2016101503         4.file
2016101504         5.file
```

So if I want to count file from time 00.00 to time 03.00, that how many file I have?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find command and specify the time range like this:

```
find -newerct 2016-10-15T00:00:00 -and -not -newerct 2016-10-15T03:00:01 | wc -l
```

- The `-newerct` allows you to give a literal timestamp that the change time is compared with.
- The range is build by combining the two times with `-and -not`.
- Depending on your use case, you might need to adopt the second string like `2016-10-15T04:00:00`.
- The matching files are piped to `wc -l` to get the file count.

There are many more useful tests for timestamps, please refer to the documentation of the **find** command.

Comment: Thanks you for best answer